# Why don't mercurial file sets work when adding files?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to use mercurial file sets to add all the files in a directory tree, excluding very large files and any binary files. Cribbing from the mercurial documentation, this command should do it:

```
hg init
hg add 'set: size("<1M") and not binary()'
```

However this returns a status code of 0, and hasn't added anything to my new, empty repo. I've tried just 'set: not binary()' and that didn't work either.
The frustrating thing is that although I can google for mercurial file sets, and find lots of examples, I can't find anything to help troubleshoot when it doesn't work!
I don't have a .hgignore file, and it's a fresh empty repo. Mercurial 4.2.2.
The directory where I'm testing this has a couple of artificially created files for the purpose of testing. In my real use case, I inherit a multi-gigbyte tarball of assorted sources and binaries from a client, and I want to get all the sources into mercurial before I start hacking to fix their problems, hence the need to exclude the binaries and large files that otherwise choke mercurial.

Here's my little test script:

```
#!/bin/sh -ex
dd if=/dev/urandom of=binary_1k bs=1 count=1024
dd if=/dev/urandom of=binary_2M bs=1 count=2097152
echo "This. Is, a SMALL text file." > text_small
hexdump binary_1k > text_1k
hexdump binary_2M > text_2M
ls -lh
file binary_1k
file binary_2M
file text_1k
file text_2M
hg init
hg add 'set: size("<1M") and not binary()'
hg status -a
hg add 'set: not binary()'
hg status -a
hg add 'set: size("<1M")'
hg status -a
```

At the end of this, each status command reports no files in the repo, and the add commands report no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that file sets do a query of Mercurial's repository data base, which knows only about files that are part of the repository or have been added.

One solution is to add all, and then to get rid of the files that you don't like, e.g.:

```
hg forget 'set:size(">1M") or binary()'
```

This works, because the query also requires recently added files, even if they haven't been committed yet.